# Variant Proof of the AM-GM Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The question at hand is:

Let $(x_i)_{1}^{n}$ be a finite sequence of positive numbers whose mean is

$m = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$

Use the fact that for each positive $t$, we have

$\log t \leq t − 1 $

to show that

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(x_i) \leq \log\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \biggr) = \log m$$

I know that this is a precursor to the AM-GM inequality but I am not allowed to use anything like Jensen's Inequality here, I have repeatedly tried to make the inequality work by applying it to each term in the sequence but have made very little progress. The answer is probably quite straightforward but I would appreciate any guidance here. Thanks

Comment: I have tried to answer your question. Please let me know if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the inequality $\log t \leq t − 1$ to the values $t = x_i / m$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left( \frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(x_i)\right) - \log(m)
&= \frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigl( \log(x_i) - \log (m)\bigr) \\
&= \frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log \left( \frac{x_i}{m}\right) \\
&\le \frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{x_i}{m} - 1\right) \\
&=  0 \, .
\end{align}
$$

*Remark:* The [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_2_(measure-theoretic_form)) of Jensen's inequality for a concave function $\varphi$ essentially uses that the graph of a concave function lies below its tangent line at a suitable point. For $\varphi(t) = \log (t)$ that would
$$
 \log(t) \le \varphi(1) + (t-1) \varphi'(1) = t-1 \, .
$$
So the above proof of the AM-GM inequality is a proof using Jensen's inequality in disguise.